# Adding expand/collapse button to DataGrid cell

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers

Here's the idea: I need an expand/collapse button in my `DataGridTemplateColumn` to allow user to expand a cell to view full contents, or collapse it to only see the first line. Here's my template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <local:ExpandCollapseButton />
            <TextBlock x:Name="MyTB" Text="{Binding Body}" Grid.Column="1" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

`ExpandCollapseButton` is a simple `UserControl` that toggles between + and - icons when clicked. It has got a read/write `bool` property named `IsExpanded`.

I'm now trying to add a simple `Trigger` to `ExpandCollapseButton`'s triggers, which would simply set `TextBlock`'s `TextTrimming` property to `WordEllipsis` in collapsed state and set it to `None` in expanded state, but can't figure out correct way of doing it. I tried adding the following code under my Expand control above:

```
<local:ExpandCollapseButton.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="MyTB" Property="TextTrimming" Value="None" />
    </Trigger>
</local:ExpandCollapseButton.Triggers>
```

but this gives error saying `Cannot find the static member 'IsExpandedProperty' on the type 'ContentPresenter'`, which I'm unable to comprehend.

Comment: You can't put Triggers in a UI Element like that. You can only add `EventTriggers` to a UI Element's Triggers collection. use `DataTemplate.Triggers` or something.

Comment: @HighCore: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DataTemplate triggers with SourceName and TargetName:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:ExpandCollapseButton x:Name="MyButton"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTB" Text="{Binding Body}" Grid.Column="1" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
    </Grid>
     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" SourceName="MyButton">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextTrimming" Value="None" TargetName="MyTB"/>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works like a charm. You can even set multiple properties of target, like I had to set both `TextTrimming` and `TextWrapping`. However for this to work, one must define trigger property (`IsExpanded` in my case) as a dependency property and not as a simple property.